# centering jquery tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i've borrowed some code from [link text](http://cse-mjmcl.cse.bris.ac.uk/blog/2008/05/15/1210851116949.html) to nest tabs using jq

everything is ok 'cept I cannot work out to center the tabs

using the YUI library, this is v easy. However, I can't use the YUI library coz my command of JS is negligible and fitting my php to their code is murderful and a time-waster.

are there ways to center jq tabs ?

Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bit of styling:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav { float: none; text-align: center; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { float: none; display: inline; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: none; }​
```

Source - [Richard Worth](http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-ui@googlegroups.com/msg06604.html)

Make sure to include this *after* the jQuery UI style-sheet so it overrides, [you can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xUj5F/).

---

If you can't use a stylesheet and *must* do this in code, use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xUj5F/1/):

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav").css({float: 'none', textAlign: 'center'});
$(".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li").css({float: 'none', display: 'inline'});
$(".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a").css({float: 'none'});
```

Comment: .ui-tabs-nav li {
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 1px;
min-width:84px;

my CSS doesn't have class .ui-tabs

Comment: @Tom - which version of jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Tom - That's jQuery, are you using jQuery UI 1.6? That's a *very* old version, have you considered upgrading?